# OSPF Area Multiple Subnets

Tags: routing, ip, ospf

Is it possible to have multiple subnets in one OSPF area? Everything I can find so far points to the answer being 'No', however I need to know for sure if it's possible or not. Our current setup is a router at each location, with a wireless backhaul link between the routers. Both sides of the wireless link have an IP address along the lines of 10.1.30.x. Network type is set to point to point and OSPF picks up the connection just fine, showing 1 neighbor on either side of the link as you would expect. However, in the scenario that the master side of the link goes down, we lose access to the slave side even if the slave router is still accessible. We are wanting to move to a scenario where one side of the link has an IP address such as 10.1.30.x but the other side would have an IP address of 10.1.29.x. Is there any way to make this work? I've been kind of thrown into this whole situation so I know very little about OSPF to begin with and am currently doing my research on that so bear that in mind.

Thanks for any help!

*Edit: The routers are Mikrotik CloudCore routers if that helps at all.

Comment: The hardware vendor must offer optional, paid support for a device to be on topic here. Unfortunately, MikroTik does not offer such support.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have multiple subnets in one OSPF area?

Yes, of course you can. Routers route *between* networks, so every router interface (both physical and logical) is on a different network. If you have multiple routers in an area, each with multiple interfaces, then you can have many networks in an area.

The point of the area is that every router in an area knows about all the other routers and networks in the area. Dividing a network into areas can help limit the resources used by the routers because they can focus on the particular area to which they are connected.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I guess now my course of action is to figure out how to establish a neighbor link on OSPF with different subnets on the backhauls for one area.